# Optimize a function to convert each character of a string to a symbol in q kdb

Tags: kdb

I have to write a function which takes integer as input argument, and return a list of symbols in alphabetical order for those many symbols.

Eg. Say, if the input to function is 4 then output should be `a`b`c`d.
P.S if the input is 27 then the output can be a-z and then repeated a.

The solution I came up with is:

```
q)f:{(`$(x;0N)#x#.Q.a)}
q)f 4
`a`b`c`d
q)f 5
`a`b`c`d`e
```

Can someone please suggest me a better/optimized solution?
Also, is there any better way to convert a string to a list of symbols other than

```
{(`$(x;0N)#x#.Q.a)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to use this function for a list/vector of integers then this quasi-vectorized approach should be quicker than function each:

```
q){x#\:`$'.Q.a}5 1 10 28
`a`b`c`d`e
,`a
`a`b`c`d`e`f`g`h`i`j
`a`b`c`d`e`f`g`h`i`j`k`l`m`n`o`p`q`r`s`t`u`v`w`x`y`z`a`b
```

Answer (score 4):

I think below should be what you are after:

```
q) {`$'x#.Q.a}5
`a`b`c`d`e
```

Answer (score 3):

You may try one below:

```
{`$/:x#.Q.a}
```

where casting to symbol `` `$ `` is applied on each element on the right.